# how to find a value contained inside a value inside an array?

Tags: php, arrays

If I have the array:

```
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
```

I know that `in_array()` is what to use if I want to find `"Mac"` inside `$os`.

But what I have the array:

```
$os = array( [1] => "Mac/OSX", [2] => "PC/Windows" );
```

and I want to see if `"Mac"` is contained in `$os`?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$example = array("Mac/OSX","PC/Windows" );
$searchword = 'Mac';
$matches = array_filter($example, function($var) use ($searchword) { return preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", $var); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this-

```
$os = array( "Mac/OSX", "PC/Windows" );    
function findInArray($os){
 foreach($os as $val){
  if(strpos($val, $word_to_search) !== false){
   return true;
  }
 }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: you should accept the answer which suits you the best... :)

Comment: I did ;-) ...still having issues with one value that doesn't return true... but I'll keep working on this before posting here

Comment: Try the edited version of my code, or post for which value this code is failing..??

Answer (score 1):

You could also use array_map to do this. Take a look at the following code:

```
$array = array(
    'Mac/OSX',
    'PC/Windows',
);



$result = in_array(true, array_map(function ($word, $match, $char = "/") {
    $words = explode('/', $word);
    return in_array($match, $words) ? true : false;
}, $array, array('Mac')));

var_dump($result); // bool(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
array_map(function($v){
    if (strpos($v, 'Mac') !== false) {
    echo 'found';
    exit;
}
},$os);

echo "Not found";
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/LqmIN)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) function of PHP like as

```
$os = array( '1' => "Mac/OSX", '2' => "PC/Windows" );

print_R(preg_grep("/Mac/",$os));
```

Output:

```
Array ( [1] => Mac/OSX )
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `foreach` and [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
$os =array("Mac/OSX","PC/Windows" );
$string = "Mac";
foreach ($os as $data) {
   //echo $data;
    if (strpos($data,$string ) !== FALSE) { 
        echo "Match found"; 
    }else{
        echo "not found";
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/rYJSU)**

Answer (score 0):

```
 function FindString($string, $os)
 {
    // put the string in between // 
    $preg = "/$string/";

    // Match found 
    $found = false;

    // loop each value 
    for($j = 0; $j < count($os); $j++)
    {
        // check with pattern 
        if(preg_match($preg,$os[$j]))
        {
            // set var to ture 
            $found = true;

            // Break 
            break;
        }
    }

    if($found == false)
    {
        die("Unable to found the string $string.");
    }

    echo "String $string found in array index $j and value is $os[$j]";

 }

 $where =array("Mac/OSX","PC/Windows" );
 $what = "Mac";
 FindString($what, $where);
```